# Bhakth prahlad chanting Om Namo Bhagvate Vāsudevāya before the birth of Lord Krishna

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita, vishnu-purana, prahlada

I was watching Vishnu Puran... i just have a doubt.. the name Vasudeva was for Lord Krishna and hence for Lord Vishnu ... But since birth of Lord Krishna was after prahlad .. how can he chant that mantra